# How to get Fairly oddparents breakin da rules to work on windows 10

Tags: technical-issues, fairly-oddparents-breakin-da-rules

I recently purchased *Fairly OddParents: Breakin' da Rules* for pc because I remember loving the game when I was younger. However I had a few problems trying to get it to work on windows 10.

I had an error pop up saying something like "Your virtual memory is off or is set too low". I then turned compatibility mode on and set it for windows xp and the game started but then crashed right away.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Specs - 
i7-6700k,
Msi 1070,
Corsair Vengeance 16gb,
750w power supply, and
Msi gaming m7 motherboard

Comment: No ideas, but a crash report log on pastebin or etc, and/or exact error message, may help someone who would know what this is realize it more easily. Just be sure to clean it so it's not giving out personal info.

Comment: version: 1.0.0.1, time stamp: 0x3f3a70df
Faulting module name: nvd3dum.dll, version: 23.21.13.8871, time stamp: 0x5a3446f0
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0097a2ce
Faulting process id: 0x1a48
Faulting application start time: 0x01d39975599cc3a9
Faulting application path: C:\Games and Programs\Games\Fairly Oddparents\The Fairly OddParents.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_d37ca5c2cde53609\nvd3dum.dll
Report Id: 6abdb631-2b76-4ea7-9383-959f92eef859
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: This is an error message from the event viewer if that helps at all.

Comment: It does seem to help point towards your video drivers, but also is leaking into SuperUser territory to try to fix it based on https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/657016/faulting-module-name-nvd3dum-dll/?offset=15

Comment: By point towards do you mean that my drivers could be out of date?

Comment: Possible, but more likely because they're too new. Really not 100% sure how to handle drivers safely though -- I rarely dealt with them on Windows when I used it, and have been using Mac for a while now with Windows only being run via a VM or similar software but never installed so hardware drivers have never been an issue.